# Get all google knowledge graph instances of a certain type

Tags: python, rest, google-knowledge-graph

I'm trying to get all instances of a certain type from google knowledge graph, so I'm using the [Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/). This is the request:

```
r = requests.get("https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search",params=dict(query="m",key=kg_key,types="TVSeries"))
```

I have to insert a value in query parameter otherwise I get this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

My question is: there is a way to obtain all istances of TVSeries type without specify query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the 'query' parameter ? The types="TVSeries" is correct.

Please see the API reference https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/